# Application built with Gradle starts successfully from IDE, but not from console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, console

I'm struggling with rather simple problem, but can't find solution nowhere.
The point is - recently I started to learn Gradle and decided to create my first Intellij project with this build tool. I use external libraries, as defined in build.gradle:

```
group 'ant.rozanski'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.3.0'
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

And project starts from Intellij 'Run' command just fine. But, unfortunately, when I try to run it from console I recieve this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory
    at model.AALJourney.setParams(AALJourney.java:40)
    at model.AALJourney.doJob(AALJourney.java:24)
    at Start.main(Start.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

It looks like gradle does not put those external libs on classpath. Why? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `application` plugin of Gradle. It provides a `run` task that has the classpath set up correctly and also tasks for building distributable packages with Windows and *nix start scripts that set up the classpath as needed.

Besides that, if what you have shown is your full `build.gradle`, the whole `buildscript` block is non-sense. You add Jackson to the classpath of the build script but you don't use it anywhere. In the buildscript block you add dependencies you need in the build script, like some Gradle plugins and so on.

Comment: Yeah, that `buildscript` block I found somewhere while searching for my problem. As I mentioned, I recently started using Gradle and it looks like I should have started learning it without Intellij first. About my problem: With that  `application` plugin I managed to run my Main class (using  `.\gradlew run Start`). Now i need to pass some command-line arguments to my application. Do You maybe know how to do it? Unfortunately google isn't helping too much. Thank You.

Comment: You can hard-code the arguments in your build script, or you can semi-hard-code the arguments in your build script by giving project properties to your program that you then can set on the gradle command line with `-P`, or you can use `installApp` instead of `run`, then you have in `build/install/` your ready-built application like it would be in the distribution zip and you can run it from there with the scripts in `bin/`, giving them any parameters like the enduser would do. You should read the Gradle Userguide, it is an excellent resource for learning Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running your class or jar from the console using something like `java -jar ..` (you don't say how you are running it from the console, or what you are running; you should clarify this in the Question if not), this seems right. The Run target in the IDE knows how to setup the classpath for your application.

There may be an IDE target to generate a runnable jar that contains refs to all the external dependencies. But if you have a bare jar you will have to invoke the JVM with a custom classpath. Or you can roll up a runnable jars that includes the third-parties libraries.

Gradle caches the dependency jars, so you might be able to use those paths to build the classpath.

Comment: I'm running using `java Class` from build directory. Gradle stores libs in .gradle directory in jars. How can I easily add them to my classpath?

Comment: The IDE has gestures to make distributable and runnable Jarfiles. I can remember how intellij idea presents these gestures in the menu, but they are there.